# Best way to find group of values in XML file

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I have XML file that represents structure of files in directory it looks similar to this

```
<dir name="dirName1">
  <file name="fileName1"/>
  <file name="fileName2"/>
  ...
  <file name="fileNameN"/>
</dir>
```

and i want to find for example files fileName1, fileName3, fileName15, is there a better way to do it than

```
for file in filenames:
   node = root.find(".//*[@name='" + file + "']")
   #do something with this file
```

Comment: If you were not about using that specific file, you might use the `|` operator in XPath and execute a single query, but in this case I think you have no better choice.

Comment: That's not enough information. Write what you are trying to achieve in the end, and also write why you think that your current approach isn't ideal.

Comment: @Gábor Bakos Ok, so I can forget about find group of files by names, and what about find all file with specific extension, for example .jpg?

Comment: @Tomalak I think it could be faster.

Comment: @Gancus I've asked you two questions in my comment. Is the other one so hard to answer? Also, *why* do you think it could be faster? Is it slow? Have you measured? How long does it take to run currently?

Comment: @Tomalak I want to get list of these nodes that represents these files. I don't know if this is slow or fast(for large xml file it can take a while), but I just think that single query could be faster than multiple queries in for loop.

Comment: @Gancus I mean it can take a while for large xml file and large amount of files to find.

Comment: But when you think about it, it will *always* be "multiple queries in a loop". You have a list of objects, and for every object you need to check a condition. Either you check for every XML node if a file exists, or for every file if an XML node exists. It heavily depends on the circumstances which way will be faster. First make it work. Then make sure it's *correct* (nobody needs a solution that's fast but occasionally wrong), and *then* make it fast, by measuring and deciding an optimization strategy. What you do here is premature optimization and it's a waste of time for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
for e in tree.findall('./fileName1'):#dirName1= root so you put ./fileName1 to have the childs
    print(e.attrib.get('name'))
```

Hope that helps